# XSLT 2.0: Limit an <analyze-string>

Tags: xslt

([fiddled](http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVQ/2))

I'm putting links to a glossary in main text.

Here is the template in a identity transform:

```
<xsl:template match="page/p/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s(beat)\s" flags="i">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <term keyref="beat">
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
            </term>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>                                
        </xsl:matching-substring>            
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>            
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the unwanted result:

```
<page>
 <p>1. Using a whip, <term keyref="beat">beat</term> egg whites..</p>
 <p>2. Add sugar; <term keyref="beat">beat</term> on medium.</p>
 <p>3. <term keyref="beat">Beat</term> at high speed until..</p>
</page>
```

Ideally, you'd only want the link in the first occurrence of the term on the page (line 1 in this example).

All my attempts to address this have been complicated and unsuccessful. Usually with XSLT, the solution is pretty simple code. But it evades me at the moment.

**UPDATE:** This seems to work (I haven't tested against all *use cases* though. (similar to Tim C's)

```
<xsl:template match="page/p/text()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- 
            count how times the word has occurred up to now,
            if 0 times, wrap it in <term> 
        -->
        <xsl:when test="count(tokenize(preceding::*[1]/text(), 'beat')) = 0">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s(beat)\s" flags="i">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <term keref="beat">
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                    </term>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>                                
                </xsl:matching-substring>            
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>            
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- the word previously occurred; leave it as is -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE**:  I used Michael Kay's suggestion and simplified this by doing it in two passes versus one.  Multi-pass turned out to very much be the right choice because the regexes became very complex. To prevent glossary links from being inserted in inappropriate places, had to use the `i` flag to enable java dialect, and then used many *look-ahead*'s. Look-behinds would have been helpful, but I could not figure out how to make them work. The `<` in the regex syntax seemed to trip things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to tag all occurrences of `beat` as you are currently doing, and then remove the unwanted occurrences in a second pass.

Comment: Oh... that may be the ticket.  Two passes with simple templates, rather than one pass with complex templates has an allure to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition to your template match, to match only `p` elements that don't have a preceding `p` which matches your expression:

```
<xsl:template match="page/p[not(preceding-sibling::p[matches(text(), '\sbeat\s')])]/text()">
```

The body of the template could remain the same in this case.

Alternately, you could put the check in the body of the template, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="page/p/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="p" select=".." />
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s(beat)\s" flags="i">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$p/preceding-sibling::p[matches(text(), '\sbeat\s')]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <term keyref="beat">
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                    </term>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>                                
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:matching-substring>            
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>            
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one approach is to key the `text()` nodes with the `matches` function and then only apply your template to the first found `text()` in each page, alike the approach taken in XSLT 1.0 with Muenchian grouping, only that in XSLT 2.0 we can use the `is` operator and we can restrict the `key` call to a subtree (of the `page`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output
        method="xml"
        omit-xml-declaration="no"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="ref-on-page" match="page/p/text()" use="matches(., '\sbeat\s', 'i')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- 
        putting links to glossary terms in text
        how to make this hit on only the first occurrence on the page?
    -->

    <xsl:template match="page/p/text()[. is key('ref-on-page', true(), ancestor::page)[1]]">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s(beat)\s" flags="i">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <term keyref="beat">
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                </term>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>                                
            </xsl:matching-substring>            
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>            
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I went in a different direction.  But I appreciate your answer.  I think I under-utilize 'key' and should use it more often. I know the few times I have used, it increased performance substantially.